# Freedman's work on non-simply-connected 4-manifolds

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, reference-request, kt.k-theory-and-homology

In the late 1970's and in the 1980's, Michael Freedman showed a relationship between the topological surgery problem in 4-dimensions, the slice problem for links, and the classification of non-simply-connected 4-manifolds. He also showed the failure of 4-dimensional homology surgery and the homology splitting theorem via a construction I don't really follow (because I haven't read and don't know the original reference, for one thing). I know of these results vaguely but do not understand them (certainly not the proofs). In particular, I don't know the "canonical" references, and MathSciNet doesn't seem to be helping me. They look like basic results in 4-manifold topology, which should surely be standard. Is there a survey paper on this stuff, or is it in some book? What is the best reference?
I should know this (or look it up myself), but perhaps it is more useful to post it here, because perhaps I am not alone in my confusion.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend you to look at the reference Freedman-Quinn book *Topology of 4-manifolds* , it might be helpful.

Comment: Also, if you're looking for original references, do a MathSciNet search Author="Freedman, Michael H" in the date range 1982-1986.  Here is a link to my search: http://www.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publications.html?pg4=AUCN&s4=Freedman%2C+Michael+H&co4=AND&pg5=TI&s5=&co5=AND&pg6=PC&s6=&co6=AND&pg7=ALLF&s7=&co7=AND&Submit=Search&yrop=eq&arg3=&dr=pubyear&yearRangeFirst=1982&yearRangeSecond=1986&pg8=ET&s8=All&review_format=html